# Trying to create an 7 GB file size on java

Tags: java

I found this code in order to create a file in a certain size:

```
    import java.io.*;

    class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
           RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("t", "rw");
           f.setLength(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
      } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

this gives me 1GB, but i want 7 GB, so i did:

```
   import java.io.*;

   class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
           RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("t", "rw");
           f.setLength(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 7);
      } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

But i am getting:

java.io.IOException: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: The value `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 7` overflows.

Comment: Dumb question, is there enough space on your disk to do this right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

7GB (in bytes) exceed the 32 bit size of an `int`. Thus it will overflow to a negative number.

So you need to make it a long:

```
  f.setLength(1024l * 1024 * 1024 * 7);
```

Comment: C# has a compiler option to detect arithmetic overflows. Java has no equivalent feature?